# Restored a Ledger Nano S seed in new Trezor Model T. Cannot restore same monero wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger, trezor

I created a Monero wallet using Monero GUI and a Ledger Nano S some time ago.

Recently, I decided to switch to Trezor and got a new Trezor Model T. I imported the same seed into the Trezor. All my other crypto wallets: BTC and ETH restore correct and I am able to use them without problems.

However, I cannot restore the same Monero wallet.
In the monero GUI I go to "Create a new wallet", I now choose "Trezor Model T" in "Hardware wallet model" but the derived wallet keys are different.

Do you know why this is the case? Am I able to restore the original wallet created using Ledger on a Trezor or I need a ledger device to access the wallet?